# where to download Hulahop module?

Tags: python, embed, pygtk, xulrunner

in this page [Embedding XULRunner into a pyGTK application](http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/no_wrap/tutorials/hulahop/xpcom-hulahop.html) looks can embed a XULApp into a pyGTK application,but i can't find the hulahop module.and where can i find it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the http://www.sugarlabs.org project. You can find a link to the Git repository on the [Dev. Modules](http://wiki.sugarlabs.org/go/Development_Team/Release/Modules) page.

Remember to check if your distro already has packages for this already if you're on Linux - quite a few do.